# How Can I delete data from Shared Preference

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am using Shared Preference in my program. In my Program there are several button each button keeps a value on it but I want to remove them in a specific time but I can't please help

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //Create Calendar-Object
        cal.setTime(new Date());
                     //Set the Calendar to now

        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //Get the hour from the calendar
        if(hour > 23)              
        {

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Count", 0);
            preferences.edit().remove("IntValue_").apply();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include exception stack trace, it is not clear what is the error. Also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "but I can't" means.

Comment: I mean I tried in many way this one was the last way I tried. it doesn't remove value from the button.

Comment: I think you are conflicting `preferences.edit()` and `editor` also `commit` and `apply`

Comment: Try using hour < 1 in your if condition. Currently, HOUR_OF_DAY never goes above 23, since it becomes 00:00 at 24

Comment: Indirect way, you can assign value of -1 instead of remove. Then when you check , just check the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY has a range of 0-23, so you'll never get a true value from `(hour > 23)`